# Integrating Bessel Functions of the first order

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to integrate the following:
$\int xJ_1(x) dx$.

I know that
$\int xJ_1(x) = (1/2)\pi{x}[H_0(x)J_1(x) - H_1(x)J_0(x)]$,
thanks to the help of wolfram. However, I cannot find the properties anywhere that relate this integral to Struve functions. Therefore, I do not know how this result is obtained. Any help in deriving this will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what about integrating the series rep of the bessel functions

Comment: Yeah I can't get the relationship